# Is there any framework for building website and mobile app with same codebase?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, jquery-mobile, ionic-framework, phonegap

I am looking for framework which will provide me website and app development with same codebase, rather than designing website and mobile app separately.

I came across phonegap and ionic frameworks, but they support multiple mobile platforms and not the website + multiple mobile platforms within a single codebase.

Is it really possible to achieve this? If so, then how?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Materialize css library](http://materializecss.com) to create cordova app based on material design guidelines. Originally this project is created to make mobile first applications with a touch of Google material design so it will definitely suit both- web and android app.

Unlike ionic, it's just a simple css and js library which is well documented and easy to use and integrate in cordova app.

Answer (score 0):

"Browser" is an ionic platform, like android and ios
You can do 'ionic cordova platform add browser' and 'ionic build browser' 
But careful with some cordova plugins not being for browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/) for building native apps with angular.